# node-mongodb-native creates sequential object ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native, objectid

Somehow mongod-native creates sequential object ids for inserted objects. I would prefer it if the database could do this job, or mongodb-native could at least use the same generation strategy as the db does.

Inserting with mongodb-native yields:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("520cc99c00bd49c20180aad0")
"_id" : ObjectId("520cc99c00bd49c20180aad1")
"_id" : ObjectId("520cc99c00bd49c20180aad2")
```

Inserting in the same collection using the shell, yields a real id:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("520cc9f25aea0256082427e9")
```

What is causing this? Isn't this a big problem for replication/sharding?

Btw. I'm using

```
db: {
    forceServerObjectId: true
}
```

already with the only effect, that the _id is not set on the object in node...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at the bytes of an `ObjectId`:

```
ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

So, if you create a series of `ObjectId`s on a single machine rapidly, you'll end up creating essentially the same `_id` as it will contain nearly the same bytes, with the exception of a 3-byte counter (as the timestamp, process id, and machine identifier will all be the same).

Most MongoDB drivers/clients create `_id`s locally by default, rather than on the Database server (and as they are all open source, you can take a look at each of the implementations to see the specifics of how the `_id` is generated. Sometimes, admittedly, it does require a bit of digging. [Here's one](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js#L106) for NodeJS for example).

The `_id` that was generated from the shell is no more "real" than the `_id`s generated from the client. They just have different seeding values (the machine and process Ids would of course be different).

By using an `ObjectId` for sharding, as of 2.4+ you've got two choices: range and hash. Each has it's pros and cons and ultimately, either work very well, depending on the nature of the writes, reads, queries, etc. that are needed. You can read more about that [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/#impacts-of-shard-keys-on-cluster-operations).

Comment: I'd leave out the sharding bit of the question, as it only confuses and doesn't relate to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have issue with sequential Object IDs , you can also create custom and random object ids

Since _id field is always indexed, and primary key, you need to make sure that different objectid is generated for each object. There are some guidelines to optimize user defined object ids :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#record-documents

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/